# VB Scipt to add Subnets to Active Directory Sites - Check is subnet exists

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I'm planning to use the following to add subnets to Active Directory Sites.

We are working on upgrading the environment to 2008 R2 so in the furture we can use powershell to administer AD, but for the moment we are doing this with VB.

```
    ' ------ SCRIPT CONFIGURATION ------
strSubnet = "<Subnet>"   ' e.g. 10.5.3.0/24
strSite   = "METRO" 
' ------ END CONFIGURATION --------

set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
set objSubnetsCont = GetObject("LDAP://cn=subnets,cn=sites," & _
                               objRootDSE.Get("configurationNamingContext") )
set objSubnet = objSubnetsCont.Create("subnet", "cn=" & strSubnet)
objSubnet.Put "siteObject", "cn=" & strSite & ",cn=sites," & _
                               objRootDSE.Get("configurationNamingContext")
objSubnet.SetInfo

WScript.Echo "Successfully created subnet " & strSubnet
```

Can someone please let me know how I can add in a line to check is the subnet already exists?

Thank you.

Amelia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://briandesmond.com/blog/script-for-bulk-import-of-active-directory-subnets/. Specifically, the `GetSubnetDN` method should be of interest.